# Make sure method is called once for each object in a List

Tags: java, mockito

I have a bunch of objects in a `List<MyClass> myObjects`, which should be used as parameters of a method call on a mocked object. I'd like to verify that the corresponding method is called exactly once for each instance in `myObjects` like

```
Iterator<MyClass> it = myObjects.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    MyClass myCurrentObj = it.next();
    Mockito.verify(myMock).add(myCurrentObj); //fail here:
}
```

With this code, I get informed that my call was not done, but other interactions on the mock happened. This is not the case if I use `Matchers.any(MyClass.class)`. Might be because the method calls on the mock don't have the same order than the corresponding parameters.

How can I verify that the method was called once for each entry in `myObjects`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use an `ArgumentCaptor` to collect all the values with which your mock was invoked:

```
final int nrElements = myObjects.size();
final ArgumentCaptor<MyClass> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyClass.class);

verify(theMock, times(nrElements)).add(captor.capture());

// This is using assertJ

assertThat(captor.getAllValues()).isEqualTo(myObjects);
```

A side effect is that this will *also* check invocation order since the captor will add captured values in order.

Comment: Good solution. "*A side effect is that this will also check invocation order*" > That just depends upon how you compare the final two lists. One could use `CollectionUtils.isEqualCollection()` to test without comparing order, if needed (from Commons Collections).

Comment: @Duncan or `assertThat(...).containsExactlyElementsOf(...)` using assertj ;)

Comment: Ooooh, I didn't know that existed. Very nice.